# tkinter filedialog opens 2 windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I Pycharm when I run:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg 
files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)

img = cv.imread(root.filename)
plt.title('Image')
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

It first opens a tk window and secondly the filedialog window.
How can I avoid the first window to be opened ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Tkinter window opening before being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187250/how-to-prevent-tkinter-window-opening-before-being-called)

Comment: Yes. Thank you !